# How to get cookie on nuxtServerInit function for static website?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am getting an error when I try to run NPM RUN generate because I use req in my nuxtServerInit to get cookies. How can I solve this?

```
nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {       
    let auth = null    
    if(req) {      
      if (req.headers && req.headers.cookie) {
        const parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie)
        try {
          auth = JSON.parse(parsed.auth)
        } catch (err) {
          // No valid cookie found
        }
      } 
    }    
    commit('SET_USER', auth)
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `req` in static mode because there is no actual request.

In static mode, `nuxtServerInit()` is run at build time.

From what I see, you are trying to create a dynamic application, so the content on the same page will differ for every user. Static pages are used for static websites, like the [nuxtjs.org](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/#static-generated-pre-rendering-) documentation.

You need to use an SPA or a Server side rendered app for what you try to do.

Comment: Thanks for your support, however, my project requires a static website. It is possible to save a token and get it back using a static site? Thanks a lot

Comment: Think about it, which token are you going to store?

Comment: Ii would like to store the tokens take came from Cognito, after the user logins in.

Comment: @gunter and myself gave all the information, you are not going to be able to achieve what you want with a static site.

Comment: So, is it possible to do auth on a static website and keep the user logged using Nuxt ?

Comment: No you can't, and it makes no sense as the page is STATIC, so you won't be able to show anything custom for the user

Comment: Sorry for necro-posting, but why can you not have user authentication on statically generated webpages? You can have api calls that populate the changing data and have the template being statically generated.  I mean, I've done it...

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot use `nuxtServerInit()` while requesting a static generated Nuxt.js app, you can change the function to be called (for example) on the app `mounted()`.
Now depending on how you've build your app, it may simple or it may be a headache.

Not to mention that it will be executed client side, which is something that you may have to rethink, but that is the nature of `nuxt generate`, craft static pages and then everything else runs on the client

Since from what I see you are only checking for cookies, you should be able to access them normally even if you run this in mounted instead of on server initialization.

Answer (score -2):

You should use universal mode, not static.
Here the same issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4066

Comment: I am using Universal. I am trying to use static hosting services.

Comment: Message from issue: "Generate not universal mode. Generate will generate static pages once. And nuxtServerInit will only be run once during generate and there wont be any request or anything.
universal mode is when u deploying your app on node.
E.g. npm run build, npm run start"

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I need to use npm run generate, and get the tokens. I gonna deploy to an AWS bucket. What should I do?

Comment: @ZeusAC No, you are not, if you are running npm run generate you are NOT using universal

Comment: Hi, sorry, Can you explain a little bit more, please?